# Orchard CMS content types relation without code

Tags: orchardcms

Probably a very simple thing to do, but I have missed it:

Scenario: 
One creates content of the type Supplier. And then starts creating content of type Product, in which the product has to be linked to the supplier (product is supplier bound, so need for a n-m relationship)

Is it possible to create two related content types (Supplier and Product). I know I can do that by programming. But I would like to follow the code less philosophy as much as possible.

UPDATE: I have answered my question below. Which brings me to a new question (I will search for an answer, but if someone knows please be my guest: Can a filter of content types that can be selected be set upfront. So that the user can only select a specific content type in the link field.

Answer (score 0):

Too fast...Just found another question where the answer was hidden in it:

Linking content items can be done easily in 1.5 using the new content picker, at least for the simplest kinds of relations.

Comment: Please tell us where that other question is.

Comment: Sorry cannot find it anymore :(